# Django Template Error 500.html on Amazon EC2

Tags: django, amazon-ec2, django-templates

First of all : I DID go through StackOverflow looking for answers, found some, but NONE worked. So here it goes again

I have this little Django project, sent it to an EC2 but I get the TemplateDoesNotExist: 500.html.

The thing is , at least for GET page, this shows up every 2 or 3 clicks ( redirects) , and when I F5 the page for 2, 3 times, it shows up again.

The file IS THERE, it just seems Django/EC2 wont look at it every now and then

I tested with debug both false and true, also tried TemplateDirs with relative, absolute and even both paths.

I tried almost everything i could find , and I am accepting every kind of solution too. BTW, i think my email is there, so, if you think is best to email me something, just do it, I would really apreciate it

Here is some code. Setting.py

`

```
# Django settings for projetoORD project.

DEBUG = False 
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
     ('omar', 'omar.sr88@gmail.com'),
)


MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'ord',                   # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'root',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': 'admin',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# In a Windows environment this must be set to your system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Sao_Paulo'


# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pt-br'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = ''

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.

    '/home/ec2-user/projetoORD/static', 

)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = '*+ikvb#(+q7-+_7x5h12kbqn058ln9q$l72hv9t1r4j-15%q1c'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'projetoORD.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'projetoORD.wsgi.application'

  TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templa$
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
        # os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'templates'),
        '/home/ec2-user/projetoORD/templates',
        '/templates',
)


INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'expressao',
)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in production mode(debug == False) django expects you to have at the root level
of your template folders a `500.html` and a `404.html`

So I guess an error/exception is happening and django tries to raise a 500 page, but can't find your 500 template.

Do you have these templates somewhere?

Comment: Specifically, that would mean either `<project dir>/templates/500.html` or `<project dir>/expressao/templates/500.html`

Comment: I have it at project dir/templates gonna just throw it at the app folder as well

Comment: @user1538724 Please tell us the full absolute path where the 500 page resides.

Comment: It is /home/ec2-user/projetoORD/templates . And I also added to it to /home/ec2-user/projetoORD/(app)/templates

Comment: @user1538724 Did you restart your server? Does the error persist?

Comment: Hi there, still having issues with restarting it, as soon as I do, i[ll tell you the results. 

  I was also thinking about something: my home.html, where user land, have some tests like {% if user.is_authenticated %} , can this be a source of error since in a fresh request there is no user?

Comment: @oSR There is always a user. It just might be an `anonymous` user. Take your time solving the restarting issues and update your post when you're ready.

Comment: Well, restarted, the error is gone, but now i got the 500 page to deal with! Thanks a  lot guys.  And now even the log erros are being sent to my email =D

Comment: @oSR Nice! Good luck with the rest.